# Ollama in Docker pulls models via interactive shell but not via RUN command in the dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ollama

I have Ollama running in a Docker container that I spun up from the official image. I can successfully pull models in the container via interactive shell by typing commands at the command-line such as:

`ollama pull nomic-embed-text`

This command pulls in the model: nomic-embed-text.

Now I try to do the same via dockerfile:

```
FROM ollama/ollama

RUN ollama pull nomic-embed-text

# Expose port 11434
EXPOSE 11434

# Set the entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["ollama", "serve"]
```

and get

```
Error: could not connect to ollama app, is it running?
------
dockerfile:9
--------------------
   7 |     COPY . .
   8 |     
   9 | >>> RUN ollama pull nomic-embed-text
  10 |     
  11 |     # Expose port 11434
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ollama pull nomic-embed-text" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

As far as I know, I am doing the same thing but it works in one place and not another. Any help?

Based on the error message, I updated the dockerfile to launch the ollama service before pulling the model. No change.

```
FROM ollama/ollama

# Expose port 11434
EXPOSE 11434

RUN ollama serve &
RUN ollama pull nomic-embed-text
```

It gave same error message.

Comment: If you're running the command via a `docker exec` debug shell, that launches an additional process in the container, where the main container command is already running.  Dockerfile `RUN` commands run in a clean environment and never have any background processes running.  I'd expect you get the same error if you ran this as the main container command, `docker run --rm ollama/ollama ollama pull nomic-embed-text`.